# Implementing Repository Pattern With RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm trying to figure out a better way to achieve something like repository pattern in RxJava in Android.

Here's what I have so far: (took some code from [here](https://gist.github.com/pieces029/5e92f9003fa1a4ebc59b))

```
public Subscription getData(Observer<Data> observer, boolean refresh) {
    Subscription sub = null;

    Data cached = getCachedData();
    if(cached != null) {
        observer.onNext(cached);
        if(refresh) {
            sub = requestNetwork().subscribe(observer);
        } else {
            observer.onCompleted();
        }
    } else {
        sub = requestNetwork().subscribe(observer);
    }

    return sub;
}
```

Basically it check if there's cached data stored, if not it'll make a network request. It also have `refresh` boolean parameter force it always make a network request.

The problem (or not) is, the caller of this function needs to call it will receive `Subscription` instead of `Observable`, which I can't chain anymore.

Is there a way to make the function return `Observable` but still have the repository pattern?

Comment: See http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/

Comment: Ah, I once opened that article but didn't use it because it used `first` that made the subscriber only got from first source that match the predicate.

I forget I could choose **not** to call the `first` operator by utilizing the `refresh` parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to akarnokd pointing me out to [this article](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/) by Dan Lew.

My final code:

```
public Observable<Data> getData(boolean refresh) {
    Observable<Data> obs = Observable.concat(getCache(), requestNetwork());
    if(!refresh) {
        obs = obs.first(data -> data != null);
    }
    return obs;
}
```

Comment: But this will emit two items when you have an item in the cache and refresh is true....

Comment: @TassosBassoukos I think that is sort of what I wanted. The view will receive the items twice. First the cache then render again the new one from network.