# Understanding How RxJava Operator Works

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm having a hard time understanding some component in RxJava and how they work.
I have these code based on [how to implement Repository Pattern with RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383010/implementing-repository-pattern-with-rxjava):

```
private Observable<String> getData(boolean refresh) {
    Observable<String> a = Observable.concat(getCache(), getNetwork());

    if(!refresh) {
        a.first(s -> s.equals("cache"));
    }

    return a;
}


private Observable<String> getCache() {
    return Observable.just("cache");
}


private Observable<String> getNetwork() {
    return Observable.just("network");
}
```

And I called the function:

```
getData(false).subscribe(s -> Log.d("Not Refresh", s));
getData(true).subscribe(s -> Log.d("Refresh", s));
// Both of them print this:
// cache
// network
```

Which doesn't right because I applied `first()` function when `refresh = true`.
Then, **I thought maybe `first()` operator didn't reflect to the original object**; so I re-assign it back.

```
if(!refresh) {
    a = a.first(s -> s.equals("cache"));
}
```

Then it worked like I wanted to and print these lines:

```
// Not Refresh cache
// Refresh cache 
// Refresh network
```

I moved on and learn on another thing, [RxBus](http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/). My code:

```
private ReplaySubject<Object> subject = ReplaySubject.create();

private <T> Observable<T> subscribe(Class<T> desiredClass) {
    return subject
            .filter(item -> item.getClass().equals(desiredClass)) // Note this line
            .map(item -> (T) item);
}

private <T> void post(T item) {
    subject.onNext(item); // This one too
}
```

Called the functions with these:

```
 sub(String.class).subscribe(s -> Log.d("Sub String", s));
 sub(Integer.class).subscribe(s -> Log.d("Sub Integer", s + ""));

 post("String A");
 post(5);

 // Result:
 // Sub String A
 // Sub Integer 5
```

When I call `sub()`, it applied `filter()` and `map()` operators and return it. **In my understanding the original subject is not changed**, then why does invoking `subject.onNext()` also invoke the modified object returned in the `sub()`?

Does it have anything to do with Subject? Or my understanding of RxJava is completely wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You miss one thing: `Subject` is both an `Observable` and `Observer`.

- `Subject` will act like an `Observable` when you call `Observable`'s methods (e.g., `filter`, `map`), and it will return a new `Observable` without changing the original one.
- However, `Subject` will act like an `Observer` when you call `Observer`'s methods (e.g., `onNext`, `onCompleted`, `onError`), and you will see side effects of these methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "side effects of these methods" part? I still don't get the idea. 
So when I do `Observable obs = mSubject.map()` the `obs` also will be automatically inherits the original `onNext()`, `onComplete()` and `onError()` from the subject?

Comment: onNext(), onComplete() and onError() are not Observable's methods. So for  `Observable obs = mSubject.map()`, the `obs` doesn't inherits them.

Comment: Ah, they're Observer methods. I still don't understand why calling subject's onNext() will also calls the Observable produced from the Subject. Need to read more about Subject.